# How to specify alignment of columns when exporting a table using Export, and how to use spaces instead of tabs?

Tags: export, list-manipulation

I have a table in list representation. How can I export it, specifying that some columns must be right-aligned and others left-aligned?
Morevoer, columns should be space-separated (with an appropriate number of spaces, to preserve alignment), not tab-separated. How can I do this?